# Can I split an array and append the output to separate arrays in one statement?

Tags: ruby

#### Edited

I originally asked about doing this in one line; I meant to say one **statement**. I've edited the question accordingly.

---

Suppose I have a method that returns a two-item array, like a color and a day of the week.

```
def make_tuple
  [['blue', 'red', 'orange'].sample, ['Mon','Wed', 'Fri'].sample]
end
make_tuple # =>  ['orange', 'Wed']
```

I can capture the output in two separate variables like this:

```
color, day = make_tuple
```

I can gather those outputs into two separate collections like this:

```
colors ||= []
days   ||= []
colors << color
days   << day
```

Is there a way to **combine these two steps** - getting separate values from the tuple and appending them to separate existing collections - into one statement? For instance:

```
# Doesn't work
colors <<, days << = make_tuple
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some examples, both functional and imperative style:

```
def make_tuple
  [['blue', 'red', 'orange'].sample, ['Mon','Wed', 'Fri'].sample]
end

# Functional creation of pairs with N elements
colors, days = 3.times.map { make_tuple }.transpose
#=> [["blue", "blue", "blue"], ["Wed", "Wed", "Mon"]]

# Functional append (creates new arrays)
colors2, days2 = [colors, days].zip(make_tuple).map { |ar, x| ar + [x] }
#=> [["blue", "blue", "blue", "red"], ["Wed", "Wed", "Mon", "Fri"]]

# Imperative append
[colors, days].zip(make_tuple) { |pair, p| pair << p } 
#=> [["blue", "blue", "blue", "red"], ["Wed", "Wed", "Mon", "Fri"]]

# Imperative append building an abstraction Array#zip_append
class Array
  def zip_append(items)
    zip(items) { |array, item| array << item }
  end
end

[colors, days].zip_append(make_tuple)
#=> [["blue", "blue", "blue", "red"], ["Wed", "Wed", "Mon", "Fri"]]
```

Comment: Wow, several array methods I didn't know about. Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in one line quite easily:

```
color, day = make_tuple; colors ||= []; days ||= []; colors << color; days << day
```

But why would you want to?

Comment: I know that I can combine lines with a semicolon. What I was really asking was whether this can be done in one statement.

Comment: BTW, I see you've been downvoted, but that wasn't me. You did answer the question I asked originally, so I'll give you an upvote. As far as "why", I'm was just curious whether it could be done. I like to keep learning new things about Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Jorg has provided a good solution.

In the meantime, you can also try making it shorter ::

`colors ||= []; days ||= []; colors << make_tuple.first && days << make_tuple.last`